# How to write a history callback in tensorflow keras that computes metrics in a validation dataset at the end of a batch

Tags: tensorflow, keras, callback

I am writing a tensorflow history callback and I would like to evaluate my model by several metrics at the end of each batch for a fixed validation dataset. I have written the following code

```
    class LossHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
        def __init__(self):
            super(LossHistory, self).__init__()
            self.mse_val = []
        
        def on_train_begin(self,logs=None):     
            self.mse_val = []
   
        def on_epoch_begin(self,epoch, logs=None):
            self.mse_val = []
        
        
        def on_batch_end(self, batch,logs=None):
            ypred = self.model.predict(validation_data[0], batch_size=1)
            self.mse_val.append(MSE_LOSS(tf.convert_to_tensor(validation_data[0],dtype=tf.float32), ypred))

mycallback = LossHistory()
mymodel.fit(training_data, training_target,validation_data= (validationd_data[0], validation_data[1]), callbacks=[mycallback])
```

The problem is that when self.model.predict is running probably it predicts with the initial weight and not the update weights after each batch. How should I fix this?

thanks

Comment: This sounds like you are guessing the problem, have you actually tried? What you said is not true.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your comment. Yes, I checked. The returned list gives me the same values for all elements. On the other hand when the epoch is over the printed validation scores are different (and lower as expected). Why do you think that what I said is not true? Thanks

Comment: Because the keras progress bar you see during training is implemented as a callback, using the same API, and the model does change from batch to batch.

Comment: You could check the progress bar logger and see how it is implemented: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.10.0/keras/callbacks.py#L994-L1169

Comment: Hi. Thank you again for the comments. The thing is that keras returns the validation logs only at the end of the epoch. I am not familiar how the API handles the logs. Do you think that I can write a simple callback that do just this? returning the validation scores at each batch step? Thank you again.